# SQL WHile Update with If conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
Declare @cnt as int
Declare @int as int
Set @int = 0
Select @cnt =COUNT(Date) FROM tmp
While @int < @cnt 
Begin


    If (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)>='00' and (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)<'15'
        Set tmp.Start_Int = Datepart(HH,Start_Time)+'00'

    else If (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)>='15' and (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)<'30'
        Set tmp.Start_Int = Datepart(HH,Start_Time)+'15'

    else If (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)>='30' and (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)<'45'
        Set tmp.Start_Int = Datepart(HH,Start_Time)+'30'

    else If (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)>='45' and (Select Datepart(MM,Start_Time) from dbo.tmp)<='59'
        Set tmp.Start_Int = Datepart(HH,Start_Time)+'45'
    end
```

As you can see, I am trying to update Start_Int to its proper intervals depending on where it falls. Using this, I get an error saying Incorrect syntax near '.'. I can assume this query is incorrect, but I cannot find any examples of a while query that uses a select to update a field if a condition is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are thrown by the `tmp.Start_Int` declarations, which I think you are trying to insert values into a database table called tmp.

You need to change:

```
Set tmp.Start_Int = Datepart(HH,Start_Time)+'00'
```

to be something like:

```
update dbo.tmp set tmp.Start_Int = Datepart(HH,Start_Time)+'00'
```

Also you might want to consider using a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to read through your data.

**EDIT**

Could you use the following as a basis?

```
declare @tmp table (Start_Time datetime)

insert into @tmp (Start_Time) values ('1-Oct-2011 21:02')
insert into @tmp (Start_Time) values ('1-Oct-2011 21:12')
insert into @tmp (Start_Time) values ('1-Oct-2011 21:22')
insert into @tmp (Start_Time) values ('1-Oct-2011 21:32')
insert into @tmp (Start_Time) values ('1-Oct-2011 21:42')
insert into @tmp (Start_Time) values ('1-Oct-2011 21:52')

select 
Start_Time, 
(case 
    when Datepart(MI,Start_Time) > 0 and datepart(MI, Start_Time) < 15 
        then cast(Datepart(HH,Start_Time) as varchar(5))+'00'
    when Datepart(MI,Start_Time) > 15 and datepart(MI, Start_Time) < 30 
            then cast(Datepart(HH,Start_Time) as varchar(5))+'15'
    when Datepart(MI,Start_Time) > 30 and datepart(MI, Start_Time) < 45 
            then cast(Datepart(HH,Start_Time) as varchar(5))+'30'
    when Datepart(MI,Start_Time) > 45  
            then cast(Datepart(HH,Start_Time) as varchar(5))+'45'
end) as Start_Int
from @tmp
```

Returns

```
Start_Time              Start_Int
----------------------- ---------
2011-10-01 21:02:00.000 2100
2011-10-01 21:12:00.000 2100
2011-10-01 21:22:00.000 2115
2011-10-01 21:32:00.000 2130
2011-10-01 21:42:00.000 2130
2011-10-01 21:52:00.000 2145
```

Comment: Start_Int is from the table dbo.tmp. I am trying to update this field, where the start_times meet the if conditions.

Comment: You need to update the tmp table then, rather than insert into it.

Comment: But you also need a way out of your while loop, so I reckon you need to be doing set @ cnt = @ cnt + 1 when you set a Start_Int value.

Comment: yes indeed! YOur example took away my errors, but are now throwing this error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. I don't think I explained this well enough, but I would like to do this on a row by row basis, hence the count. However, I assume the select and update isnt just grabbing it row by row, correct?

Comment: Just a minute I'll rewrite this

Comment: Ok, I understand this code, but at which point do I do the actual updating?

Comment: Use the case expression and instead of your code do: update tmp set Start_Int = (case when ... end)

Comment: Ahh! Makes sense! Thanks a lot for this, I know this stuff is elementary to a lot of people on here.